# Is acceleration changing in harmonic motion always

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator, angular-velocity

I encountered a question in which particle displacement at an instant was given by $$y=\sin(\omega t-\theta)$$ if differentiate this we get velocity and again differentiating we get acceleration but since this is a sine function that means it must continuously differentiable does this means acceleration is always changing and so is the rate of change of acceleration

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Simple harmonic motion can be defined by the relationship that acceleration is toward a fixed point and proportional to the displacement from that point. $$\ddot y = -\omega^2 y.$$

Comment: That means that acceleration is constantly increasing

Comment: You are ignoring the minus sign